# Excel VBA debug Recorded Macros

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am new to this Excel VBA , I am getting a runtime compilation error in the following Macro -

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "EmployeeID"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.Select
    Selection.Replace What:="0", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Selection.Replace What:="1", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Selection.Replace What:="2", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=ActiveCell. _
        Offset(-1,0).Range("A:A"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending,
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
```

Please help me with the error in the code.
Thanks

Comment: What line is causing the error and what is the error description?

Comment: Missing line continuation on the second to last line.

Comment: `Key:=ActiveCell. _
        Offset(-1,0).Range("A:A")` looks weird too.

Comment: If you try to offset 1 column to the left of `A` or one row up from `1` it will fail as they do not exist

Comment: @DarrellH correct, but that would be error 1004 at run-time :)

Answer (score 2):

You're getting a *compile* error, not a *run-time* error. Compilation errors are the VBA compiler saying "I don't know what this is saying, I can't run it"; run-time errors happen when the code compiles and runs, and then suddenly blows up and you're in *break mode* and need to debug to resume execution.

The macro recorder has a tendency to "inject" **line continuation** tokens to split up long member calls into multiple "physical lines"; in VBA line continuations can make a "logical" line of code span up to 20 "physical" lines in the source code file.

The token is defined as a space followed by an underscore, then a new line.

The problem is that the recorder will break up an instruction anywhere it's legal to do so, without regards to readability: it's not rare for it to split up named arguments at the `:=` operator, and in the current case we have a member call (`Range.Offset`) separated from its qualifying dot (`ActiveCell.`).

First thing to do when cleaning up macro recorder code, is to get rid of all the line continuations.

```vb
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "EmployeeID"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.Select
Selection.Replace What:="0", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:="1", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:="2", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=ActiveCell.Offset(-1,0).Range("A:A"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
```

Now that all the instructions are legal and the code compiles, we can look into tweaking it to make it less redundant and more efficient.

We're dependent on the `ActiveCell` - that's fine, but we will want to avoid dereferencing the active cell more than once, and we can do that by introducing a *variable*, using the `Dim` keyword. Cells are `Range` objects in the Excel object model, so we declare our variable `As Range`, and then we *assign* it using the `Set` keyword, because it's an object:

```
Dim cell As Range
Set cell = ActiveCell
```

Then we can do the same for the active sheet - like this:

```
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = ActiveSheet
```

Or like this (technically more reliable):

```
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = cell.Parent
```

The macro is making that cell's `FormulaR1C1` a literal string value: that's really more a *value* than a *formula*, let alone a *formula in R1C1 notation*. Setting the cell's `Value` would make the code more explicit about its intent:

```
cell.Value = "EmployeeID"
```

Note that *whatever the active cell is* is getting this "EmployeeID" value: code should either validate that the cell is in row 1, or specifically write the value in row 1 if that's what it means to do:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, cell.Column).Value = "EmployeeID"
```

Next we *select the entire column* and then work off `Selection` to find/replace things. We don't need to `.Select` anything, really:

```
With cell.EntireColumn
    .Replace What:="0", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    .Replace What:="1", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    .Replace What:="2", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
End With
```

That's redundant, we can eliminate the need for copy-pasting chunks of code by moving that part into a separate `Private Sub` procedure scope that only does this:

```vb
Private Sub ClearValueInColumn(ByVal Column As Range, ByVal Value As String)
    Column.Replace What:=Value, _
                   Replacement:=vbNullString, _
                   LookAt:=xlPart, _
                   SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                   MatchCase:=False, _
                   SearchFormat:=False, _
                   ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

Now the `With cell.EntireColumn` block above, can become this:

```
ClearValueInColumn(cell.EntireColumn, "0")
ClearValueInColumn(cell.EntireColumn, "1")
ClearValueInColumn(cell.EntireColumn, "2")
```

The next instruction is problematic:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.Select
```

If the `ActiveCell` (or our `cell` variable) is in row 1, offsetting negative 1 rows is going to blow up, because worksheets don't have a row (or column) 0.

The good news is that the `Offset` is redundant, because again what we're *really* looking at is just `cell.EntireColumn`, and again we don't need to `Select` anything, but then the next line is also doing redundant dereferencing:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 ...
```

The `cell` variable is referring to a cell on the active sheet, so what we really want here is to get the *parent sheet* of that `cell`, rather than to pull a sheet named "Sheet1" (which the user might rename any time - that would instantly break the code!). We've already pulled that object reference into a `sheet` variable, so let's use it:

```vb
sheet.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=cell.EntireColumn, _
                           SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                           Order:=xlAscending, _
                           DataOption:=xlSortNormal
```

Note that the negative row `Offset`, as well as the `.Range("A:A")` member call, are redundant. Avoid any row offsets when you're working with an entire column - *especially* negative offsets that could attempt to select a cell that's outside the worksheet; always validate that `ActiveCell.Row` and `ActiveCell.Column` are large enough to take the subtraction without turning zero or negative.

Lastly, if the macro doesn't really need to work off *whatever the active cell is*, but is really assuming that the user has selected a specific cell before running the macro, then you can set your `cell` to the actual cell you need the macro to work with instead of getting the current selection involved - for example this would make the macro work off cell E4:

```
Set cell = ActiveSheet.Range("E4")
```

So, that makes the cleaned-up macro look like this:

```vb
Public Sub Macro1()

    Dim cell As Range
    Set cell = ActiveCell

    ReplaceValueInColumn(cell.EntireColumn, "0")
    ReplaceValueInColumn(cell.EntireColumn, "1")
    ReplaceValueInColumn(cell.EntireColumn, "2")

    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Set sheet = cell.Parent

    sheet.Cells(1, cell.Column).Value = "EmployeeID"

    sheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    sheet.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=cell.EntireColumn, _
                               SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                               Order:=xlAscending, _
                               DataOption:=xlSortNormal
End Sub

Private Sub ReplaceValueInColumn(ByVal Column As Range, ByVal Value As String)
    Column.Replace What:=Value, _
                   Replacement:=vbNullString, _
                   LookAt:=xlPart, _
                   SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                   MatchCase:=False, _
                   SearchFormat:=False, _
                   ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```